# Loading usernames with AJAX - Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using this gem: https://github.com/ichord/jquery-atwho-rails

Within my controller:

```
@usernames = User.pluck(:username).compact
```

Within my view:

```
<script>

data = <%= raw User.pluck(:username).compact %>; 
$('textarea').atwho({at:"@", 'data':data});

</script>
```

This is obviously very dangerous and not a good idea. But for someone with no AJAX or Javascript experience, how do I use this gem and call on the usernames through AJAX in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `remote_filter` callback:

```
$('#textarea').atwho({
        at: "@",
        show_the_at: true,
        callbacks: {
            remote_filter: function(query, callback) {
                // Return false on empty query
                if (query.length < 1) {
                    return false
                }
                // AJAX call to http://yoursite/users.json?q=query
                $.getJSON("/users.json", {q: query}, function(data) {
                    callback(data.usernames)
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

And you should write some simple handling of the "q" parameter (in this case) in the /users.json call. Here some sample code for it:

```
# controllers/users_controller.rb
def index
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json{ render :json => User.where('username like ?', "#{q}%").pluck(:username).compact}
  end
end
```

You can find more here:
https://github.com/ichord/At.js/wiki/How-to-use-remote_filter

Comment: Thanks! Where do I past the Javascript/ajax snippet above?

Comment: Where you current one is. Or in application.js within a $(function(){}); block. About the second question: you should put it in the index method, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you said. I put the code in place of the current script and nothing is happening now.

Comment: $('#textarea') - look at the '#' before 'textarea'. It means that your textarea should be with id="textarea", or however you wish to name it. For example if it's $('#users-textarea').... you should put an id attribute of your textarea 'users-textarea' like this: <textarea id="users-textarea"></textarea>